# How do I carry over previous "likes" to new, upgraded domain address? How do I link website with the FB page?

Tags: facebook, dns, blogs, hyperlink

I have very little knowledge how the plug ins work and really need help. I have a blogging website that I just upgraded to a regular domain address. The original site was http://meltfitness.blog.com. now the domain address is http://meltfitness.net. I'm trying to find out if there is any way TO NOT LOSE the previous likes the pages had from the original domain. Is there a way to carry those over to the new domain? This problem only seems to be happening on the individual posts; not the general site itself. ALSO, when someone clicks "like" on my site/page/posts, it is not carrying over into their "Likes" section on FB. It DOES seem to show up as a recent like, but it doesn't intertwine with my meltfitness.net FB page. PLEASE, PLEASE, PLEASE HELP!! I've spent hours and days trying to figure this out but I'm simply not tech savvy!

Comment: Oh, i ready this entirely wrong. Looks like you're right. At least I can stop stressing over it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you might be unable to do this.

Read:

www.allfacebook.com/likes-domains-transfer-2010-08

and

uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110628163905AAPh02C

I can't find any Facebook documentation stating that is impossible.
You might be able to  get help from Facebook at http://www.facebook.com/help

Good luck

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! I will try this and let you know if this takes care of the issue. Thanks again!